# Extend PGP license of secret key in other server

Tags: gpg, pgp

I'm facing an issue with extending the validity of the PGP license.

I've generated a key in server1 and exported publicKey to server2 for encryption , and secretkey to server3 for decryption one year back.

Now the license will expire in 2 days and need to extend the license.

I've ran the commands below in Server1 and extended the license for another year
gpg --edit-key keyabc

Exported the extended public key to server2 and I'm good there. But the actual problem is with server3. I've imported the secertKey to Server3 for decryption, but it won't show the extended date of license, shows old expiry date instead.

Some reason I'm not allowed to directly login to server3 and run "expire" commands to extend the license. It has to be done by importing....

What happens after the expiry date? Will the keys still able to decrypt the files in server3? what options should I try?

Couldn't find suitable answers online.

appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is google no help?

Comment: Unfortunately nope :(